# Traefik + Docker Swarm + Cloudflare: Service is Up but hostname is 404 not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, cloudflare, traefik

i am attempting to run traefik into docker swarm with cloudflare dns by following this tutorial https://dockerswarm.rocks/traefik/.

Here is my traefik docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:latest
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command:
      - "--api"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.watch=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.postgres.address=:25060"
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - "--entrypoints.dashboard.address=:8081"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    environment:
      - "CLOUDFLARE_DNS_API_TOKEN=it is secret"
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8081:8080"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.traefik-public.traefik-public-certificates == true
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "traefik-public-certificates:/letsencrypt"
volumes:
  traefik-public-certificates:

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

and deployed it with the following command:

```
jais@ip-11 server % docker stack deploy --compose-file traefik2.yml proxy
Creating service proxy_traefik
```

the service is up and i go to the dashboard:
[image: traefik dasboard is up]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPM3z.png

Yep, dashboard is working fine. Then i want test the traefik by deploying simple whoami service from traefik with following docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=le"
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

then i deployed it with command:

```
jais@ip-11 server % docker stack deploy --compose-file app.yml app
Creating service app_whoami
```

it works fine. Then check the log to make sure app is running.

```
jaismarine@ip-10-13-13-3 server % docker service logs app_whoami
app_whoami.1.4huexnutnx5v@ip-172-31-23-3    | 2022/08/06 12:59:22 Starting up on port 80
```

Yep it is up. I check into traefik service logs:

```
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one" tlsStoreName=default
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="*docker.Provider provider configuration: {\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmMode\":true,\"network\":\"traefik-public\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":\"15s\"}"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.ChallengeTLSALPN"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="*acme.ChallengeTLSALPN provider configuration: {}"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.Provider"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="*acme.Provider provider configuration: {\"email\":\"alihalabyah@gmail.com\",\"caServer\":\"https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\",\"storage\":\"/letsencrypt/acme.json\",\"keyType\":\"RSA4096\",\"certificatesDuration\":2160,\"dnsChallenge\":{\"provider\":\"cloudflare\"},\"ResolverName\":\"le\",\"store\":{},\"TLSChallengeProvider\":{},\"HTTPChallengeProvider\":{}}"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Attempt to renew certificates \"720h0m0s\" before expiry and check every \"24h0m0s\"" ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=le.acme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..." providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=le.acme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 20.10.17 (API 1.41)" providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=tracing
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareType=Recovery middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik routerName=api@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware dashboard@internal" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal middlewareType=StripPrefix
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection from ^(http:\\/\\/(\\[[\\w:.]+\\]|[\\w\\._-]+)(:\\d+)?)\\/$ to ${1}/dashboard/" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one" tlsStoreName=default
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=viz-dvk733grckjpkex71pyx03krr
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=registry-rdlul6pd5hx91jkmd650bwzej
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:57Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) jais.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) uhu.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" entryPointName=traefik routerName=api@internal middlewareType=TracingForwarder middlewareName=tracing
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware dashboard@internal" entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal middlewareType=StripPrefix entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection from ^(http:\\/\\/(\\[[\\w:.]+\\]|[\\w\\._-]+)(:\\d+)?)\\/$ to ${1}/dashboard/" middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one" tlsStoreName=default
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) jais.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) uhu.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=tracing
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal middlewareType=RedirectScheme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" middlewareType=RedirectScheme entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=web
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" routerName=api@internal entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware dashboard@internal" middlewareName=tracing entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareType=TracingForwarder
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal middlewareType=StripPrefix entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection from ^(http:\\/\\/(\\[[\\w:.]+\\]|[\\w\\._-]+)(:\\d+)?)\\/$ to ${1}/dashboard/" middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:58:58Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:12Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=proxy-traefik-5nt0t4uqvjfmcmk89a1g2cjon
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:12Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=viz-dvk733grckjpkex71pyx03krr
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:12Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=registry-rdlul6pd5hx91jkmd650bwzej
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:12Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:12Z" level=debug msg="Skipping unchanged configuration." providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:27Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=proxy-traefik-5nt0t4uqvjfmcmk89a1g2cjon
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:27Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" container=viz-dvk733grckjpkex71pyx03krr providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:27Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=registry-rdlul6pd5hx91jkmd650bwzej
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:27Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"whoami\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"whoami-service\",\"rule\":\"Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"le\"}}},\"services\":{\"whoami-service\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://10.0.2.194:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:27Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one" tlsStoreName=default
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) jais.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) uhu.sheralink.com"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware dashboard@internal" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal middlewareType=StripPrefix entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal middlewareName=dashboard_stripprefix@internal entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection from ^(http:\\/\\/(\\[[\\w:.]+\\]|[\\w\\._-]+)(:\\d+)?)\\/$ to ${1}/dashboard/" middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal middlewareType=RedirectRegex entryPointName=traefik routerName=dashboard@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" routerName=dashboard@internal entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=dashboard_redirect@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware api@internal" routerName=api@internal middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=traefik
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=traefik middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware noop@internal" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" routerName=web-to-websecure@internal entryPointName=web middlewareType=RedirectScheme middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Setting up redirection to https 443" entryPointName=web middlewareType=RedirectScheme middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal routerName=web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding tracing to middleware" entryPointName=web routerName=web-to-websecure@internal middlewareName=redirect-web-to-websecure@internal
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" serviceName=whoami-service routerName=whoami@docker middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=websecure
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=websecure serviceName=whoami-service routerName=whoami@docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://10.0.2.194:80" routerName=whoami@docker entryPointName=websecure serverName=0 serviceName=whoami-service
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="child http://10.0.2.194:80 now UP"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Propagating new UP status"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware whoami-service" entryPointName=websecure routerName=whoami@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Adding route for uhu.sheralink.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=websecure
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Try to challenge certificate for domain [uhu.sheralink.com] found in HostSNI rule" ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" routerName=whoami@docker rule="Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)" providerName=le.acme
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"uhu.sheralink.com\"]..." routerName=whoami@docker rule="Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)" providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:28Z" level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"uhu.sheralink.com\"]." routerName=whoami@docker rule="Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)" providerName=le.acme ACME CA="https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:42Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=proxy-traefik-5nt0t4uqvjfmcmk89a1g2cjon
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:42Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" providerName=docker container=viz-dvk733grckjpkex71pyx03krr
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:42Z" level=debug msg="Filtering disabled container" container=registry-rdlul6pd5hx91jkmd650bwzej providerName=docker
proxy_traefik.1.5nt0t4uqvjfm@dog.example.com    | time="2022-08-06T12:59:42Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"whoami\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"whoami-service\",\"rule\":\"Host(`uhu.sheralink.com`)\",\"tls\":{\"certResolver\":\"le\"}}},\"services\":{\"whoami-service\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://10.0.2.194:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
```

No error, but there is debug message:

```
"No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"uhu.sheralink.com\"]."
```

I was expecting can access whoami service by opening host domain `uhu.sheralink.com` but turns out it returns 404 not found:

[image: whoami 404 not found]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWx3.png

Anyone can help me why traefik does not routes my request from `uhu.sheralink.com` through whoami service ?

Any hints or answer, would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I am not an expert in this topic, myself I've just struggled with it for like 8 hours.

I am not sure exactly where the problem is in you case, your yml files for the most part mirrors mine but perhaps the error is in how you define the `traefik-public` network.

Perhaps try this instead:

```yaml
networks:
  traefik-public:
    driver: overlay
    name: traefik-public
    attachable: true
```